# Windows hybernate vs shutdown + boot up times: Why choose for hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10, shutdown, hibernate

After reading [this post](http://www.techspot.com/review/1042-windows-10-vs-windows-8-vs-windows-7/), a comparison between the different boot times and hibernate times of the different windows OS's of today, I wondered why would I want to hibernate my pc/laptop?

Considering shutdown takes less then 10 seconds and the boot-up takes approx. 10 seconds, this would take a total of 20 seconds and no energy use while off. Whereas hibernate alone takes 23 seconds and the wake-up takes 10 seconds.

Why would I still want to hibernate, considering it takes longer and uses little energy?

Comment: Hibernation made more sense in 1999 than it does now (which is ironic since it rarely worked right back then). Also, be sure to consider the time it takes to reopen files and applications from your prior session. In theory laptops are supposed to be "on the go" so closing it at split second notice, and then opening it later like nothing interrupted you is desirable.

Comment: Wake up for hibernation *10 seconds* I don't think I agree... It is a littler quicker than normal boot up (8 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernation writes the entire memory state of your computer to disk.  This means that even if your laptop runs out of power, or you pull the battery, when it's turned back on again you'll be brought right back to the place you left off.  If you had just slept the computer and it ran out of power, you'd have to reboot entirely.

Even though boot times are vastly quicker these days, and battery capacity much higher, hibernation still has a place for some users.  They might run a lot of applications, or have work open they don't want to risk losing.  But the upcoming prospects of non-volatile system memory will take away even that use case.  So yes, every year there's less and less reason to bother with hibernation over sleep or shutdown.

Comment: Hibernate is good for solid-state drives. But then again, why hibernate when you have the luxury of fast cold-boot times?

Answer (score 1):

I **ONLY use hibernation** (I only reboot 1 time per month after installing security updates) because it restores my Windows at resume to the same state as before doing hibernation. So all my applications are still open and I can continue to work immediately. Even with this fastboot of Windows 8 (wich is log off + hibernation of the kernel) it requires to load all start up programs which is still slow. but resuming the applications after hibernation is dramatically fattier.